# How to get the latest date when reading from file?

Tags: c

In this code, I am trying to read the latest date but it is printing the whole data from the file, which I don't want. I tried all the code in the main function and it was working well.

But in the record function, it didn't give me the required result. How to make this working, just to print the latest date from both files.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXC 1024     
#define MAXDT 16

typedef struct {       
    char datestr[MAXDT];   
    unsigned dateval;
} datestrval;

int record(char *buf){                        
    datestrval max = { .datestr = "" };  
    do{     
      unsigned mo, day, yr;      
      char *p = strrchr (buf, ','),    
        tmpstr[MAXDT] = "";  
      unsigned tmpu = 0;         
        
      if (!p)                           
        continue;
      if(sscanf(p + 1,"%u-%u-%4u",&day, &mo, &yr)!= 3)
        continue;
      sprintf (tmpstr, "%04u%02u%02u", yr, mo, day); 
      if (sscanf (tmpstr, "%d", &tmpu) != 1)
        continue;
      if (tmpu > max.dateval) {     
        max.dateval = tmpu;           
        strcpy (max.datestr, p + 1);
        max.datestr[strcspn (max.datestr, "\n")] = 0;
      }
    }while(0);

    printf ("last date in file: %s\n", max.datestr);
    return 0;  }
```

**Main**

```
int main(){
  char string[MAXC];
  FILE * fp = fopen("file.csv", "r");
  FILE * fp1 = fopen("new.csv", "r");

  while (fgets(string, MAXC, fp)) { 
    record(string);
  }
  while(fgets(string, MAXC, fp1)){
    record(string);
  }
}
```

Comment: you're reading each line and feeding it to `record`. No global state across all lines are held. You need to instead feed the whole data of the file and determine the maximum date from there

Comment: @Chase I didn't understand.

Comment: You don't store the latest date **between** both calls of `record()`.

Comment: @thebusybee How can I save the latest date when calling `record()`? That's what I want to know.

Comment: please shorten your question according to [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I save the latest date when calling `record()`?

You can save it in a global variable. Change `typedef struct { … } datestrval;` to `struct { … } max;` and delete the line

```
    datestrval max = { .datestr = "" };
```

then you don't lose the date information. Move the line

```
    printf ("last date in file: %s\n", max.datestr);
```

to the end of `main` in order to print only one *last date*.